# Referencing top-level properties in nested filter

Tags: elasticsearch

In Elasticsearch, is it possible to reference a top-level (non-nested) property in a nested filter?

I have a situation where I need a condition to be true either at a global level or in one of any number of associated nested objects.  Inside of the nested filter I have an or-filter to check one or the other, but the outer property appears to be ignored.  An example is [here](http://sense.qbox.io/gist/a63703a6753cee51f2cc0c3fa65854607726b538).

I have a feeling that what I'm needing is not supported and everything inside of the nested-filter must apply at or below the specified path (from the [docs](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html), **"The query is executed against the nested objects / docs as if they were indexed as separate docs (they are, internally)"**.  I'm about to just duplicate the top-level data in each nested object (it really is just a boolean field), but I'd like to know if this is possible or if there's another obvious solution I'm missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in that the feature you are looking for is not supported. Elasticsearch uses the various Lucene join queries such as ToParentBlockJoinQuery underneath and it does not reference both layers of properties.

You can use the include_in_parent/include_in_root properties to push the property to a higher level, but you lose the ability to filter on multiple properties belong to the same nested document.